# Creating XML file with XML Schema : MalformedByteSequenceException

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to create XML document with specified XML Schema file using JAXB. When I ran my application in Eclipse, it worked fine. Later I built runnable jar. Application was working good but when I tried to save file I got an error, which doesn't exist in Eclipse:
**MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence**

There are functions which are responsible for whole process:

```
private String generateXML() throws JAXBException, BladWalidacjiXml {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
            .newInstance(RootClass.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    StringWriter xmlDocument = new StringWriter();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(rootClass, xmlDocument);
    String xml = xmlDocument.toString();
    try {
        XmlParser.validateWithXSD(xml);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new BladWalidacjiXml(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new BladWalidacjiXml(e);
    }
    return xml;

}

public static void validateWithXSD(String xml) throws SAXException, IOException {
    validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())));
}

private static boolean validate(StreamSource xmlFile) throws SAXException,     IOException{
    File schemaFile = new File(SCHEMA_FILE_PATH);
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
            .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(xmlFile);
    return true;
}
```

Nodes in XML may include Polish national signs such as "ą","ę","ź" etc. I suppose that isn't the reason of error but maybe I'm wrong.

I would be grateful for any help.

EDIT:
Code that create XML file:

```
public void saveToFile() throws JAXBException, IOException,
        BladWalidacjiXml {

    PrintWriter ostream = null;
    boolean deleteFile = false;
    try {
        ostream = new PrintWriter("file.xml", "UTF-8");
        ostream.write(generateXML());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        deleteFile = true;
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        deleteFile = true;
        throw e;
    } catch (BladWalidacjiXml e) {
        deleteFile = true;
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (ostream != null) {
            ostream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that create the xml file?

Comment: I've found solution - encoding has to be set in validateWithXSD function like this: 
xml.getBytes("UTF-8");